# Search box disappears on search result page when using a customer masterpage

Tags: 2010, search, master-page, branding, custom-masterpage

I have created a custom master page. I display the search box on the page using the following code:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:DelegateControl ID="DelegateControl6" runat="server" ControlId="SmallSearchInputBox" Version="4" />
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

This displays the search box in the top right hand corner of a page. When I perform a search on the search results page /Pages/Results.aspx the search box is not there. The same master page is used on both pages.

How can I get the search box to remain on every page?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to remove the search box from the PlaceHolderSearchArea as that is the control that is replaced when the search page renders